# What's the best option to repair a long asphalt driveway with heavily cracked portions?

Tags: driveway, asphalt

I have a long-ish driveway (about 50 - 80 feet and 10 feet wide?)...it's about 10 years old, have heavy cracks in the beginning, middle, and end, but otherwise still serviceable. What are my options to repair the cracks and the durability/cost of the options (and which would you recommend)? Not an expert in this area, but my thoughts are:

1. Seal the cracks with stuff like GemSeal
2. Pave over the entire driveway with a new layer of asphalt
3. Dig up the cracked areas and put in new portions (is that even possible?)
4. Replace entire driveway

Comment: If it cracked heavily in only 10 years then it doesn't have a good base, making options 2 and 3 a waste of money.

Comment: Actually, it may be 15 years...but yeah, sounds like the foundation isn't good.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not sure about GemSeal or similiar stuff, but if You live in hard climate area, won't last for long, to be sure.
2. That will crack in next year or so.
3. Possible, but depends on how long these cracks are and what kind of these are (what forces cause this problem). I wouldn't recomend that.
4. Good idea, especially in harsh climate, where ground freezes in winter, and - if underbed of Your current layer is rather badly done. It may be done with other material than asphalt. There are some materials like brick paving. You could do this Yourself probably. Don't forget to make good substructure.

If You are short on money, try 1.(not sure) or 3.(You will need some devices and helping hands).  If You got some savings and want to to this really nice and good-looking, choose 4. (which I strongly prefer).

Comment: Yes, I'm in Connecticut, so there are extreme swings in temperatures from winter to summer.

Comment: Also, I don't think the development where I'm in will let me pave with anything other than asphalt.